# How do I return from a promise in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

I want to return `subjects` from this function, but I always get `undefined`.

```js
getNewItems() {
        imap.connect(this.config).then((imapCon) => {
            imapCon.openBox("INBOX").then(() => {
                let searchCriteria = [
                    'UNSEEN'
                ];
                let fetchOptions = {
                    bodies: ['HEADER', 'TEXT'],
                    markSeen: false
                };
                imapCon.search(searchCriteria, fetchOptions).then((result) => {
                    let subjects = result.map((res) => {
                        return res.parts.filter((part) => {
                            return part.which === 'HEADER';
                        })[0].body.subject[0];
                    });
                    return subjects;
                })
            })
        })
```

I tried using awaits but this only resulted in getting a promise from the function

Comment: Well, you need to return all your promises, `return imap.connect(...)`, `return imapCon.openBox(...)`, `return imapCon.search(...)`.

Comment: What is the output of result.map  when you step through your code ?

Comment: @Twiggeh It's an array of email subjects

Comment: then if [0].body.subject[0]; isn't undefined @sp00m 's answer is what you are looking for

Comment: You're performing multiple asynchronous operations, so you'll need to handle the response by either returning a promise or providing some kind of callback.. The former is preferred.